# Cursor ghostly jumps with touchscreen in 11.10

Tags: xorg, touchscreen

I think this is related to xserver somehow, but when I'm using paint programs like Gimp or Inkscape in 11.10 with either the pen or touch inputs, occasionally the cursor will just jump to the edge of the screen, ruining the whole line, and making drawing impossible.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Some things that might be relevant?

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1676062&page=2

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1785015.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular jumping problem disappeared on update to 12.04.  (I have new problems with the touch screen averaging inputs between cursor and touch, of course, but the original problem is solved, somehow.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use xinput to set a Coordinate Transformation Matrix for X? If yes, follow this bug:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50664

In any case, your problem might be related to the fact that X autoconfigures itself to share the mouse pointer between all pointing devices. This way, the touchscreen/tablets interfere with the mouse and vice-versa.
A possible solution may be found here:
http://www.harbaum.org/till/cnc/cx-t100/index.shtml

Comment: I didn't use the coordinate transform, this was something different.  I think it was solved on update to 12.04.